# Unity Engine: Loading images during runtime (optimization issue)

Tags: c#, optimization, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a project in Unity which requires accessing images from a "Resources" folder and loading them as Sprites, for use during runtime.

The sprites in question aren't needed until the user opens a particular window. Only then they are necessary. The thing is, there are 150+ images (resolutions between 120x120 and 512x512) to be accessed, and only one image at a time will be shown (at any moment) during the execution of the game.

So my question is: Which option is better from an optimization standpoint?

1. To load all images as sprites into variables at the beginning of the game and then use them as they are necessary?
2. Load the images only when they're necessary?

Possibly important info: I'm using Resources.Load() to access all sprites I need

I don't know if the question has a "linear" answer. If the question is difficult to understand, or isn't answered as easily as I thought, please inform me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could load them all at once on a background thread when the program is launched. They're done loading by the time the splash screen is done. See System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

Comment: What is the code you use to load the images now? Do you currently load them as an array? @ShannonHolsinger He can't use that in Unity since Unity API are not allowed to be used from another Thread.

Comment: My bad - I thought you could load them async as long as you accessed them synch.

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger That's a nice idea :) Is there anything more similar to threads in Unity than Coroutines? I have the impression they're not the same, but I don't remember anything else in Unity which might look like multithreading.

Comment: @Programmer I don't have the code yet, but I'm thinking of a list containing the sprites for each image, yes. I'm thinking. 1st: Creating an empty list 2nd: Use Resource.Load() to load the image as a sprite and using <ListName>.Add() to add the sprite to the list.

Comment: @Programmer so you can't work in threads in Unity? That's a bummer :|

Comment: You can use Threads in Unity but you can't call Unity API from those Thread. You have to call pass the data back to Unity's main Thread. How often do you need the images? For example, when do they load and unload? If you explain what you are doing, maybe there is even a better way to do this.

Comment: The images are part of a "help" window which can be accessed anytime during the game. It's a strategy 4X game, and the window gives detailed info of each unit, building, terrain type, etc. in the game. So they should be ready to use at any moment. Just a right-click on the world map will bring the said window to the front of the screen.

Comment: If that's the case, then you should load them all into an array. If you don't want freezing when loading them, use [Resources.LoadAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAsync.html)

Comment: @Programmer Indeed it would be better if the resources were loaded without freezing. I'll use it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say use something like [Texture Packer](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to put them into a single sprite sheet, that way you are loading a small number of large images, which typically runs faster than a large number of small images.  Then you can piece it out as needed.  You'll see increased performance since you're sending less to the GPU every frame too.

As for the options you gave though, I'd favor pre-loading the images rather than waiting until they are needed.  Unless you are super concerned about saving space, better to make the scene-load slightly longer (when everything is frozen anyway, and gamers are familiar with loading screens at this point) than to wait until the player is already in the game, engaged, and suddenly they have to break [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)) for a second and figure out if the game just froze.  They won't know what you're doing and it'll just detract from the experience.

Comment: Didn't think of that :) Thank you for your help and your opinion. +1 for that flow hyperlink :D

Comment: @Dayman75 whenever I come to a point where there are 2-3 different ways to implement something, always fall back on which best serve the design.  Keeping flow in mind during your decision making almost always works out in the end.

Comment: If you are using one of the latest unity then you dont require texture packer. Unity has its own SpritePacker, you can use that too. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpritePacker.html

Comment: @ZohaibJaved I didn't know it was built in now, I'm glad to hear that happened.  I'm still using a slightly older version so I didn't hear about that.